# BeanInstantiationException due to java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I am running an annotation-based configuration project such as :

```
@Configuration
public class HibernateConfig {

    private Map<String, String> map;

    public HibernateConfig(){
        init();
    }

    private void init(){
        Properties props;
        InputStream input = null;
        try {
            props = new Properties();
            input = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("jdbc.properties");
            props.load(input);
            Enumeration<?> e = props.propertyNames();
            while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
                String key = (String) e.nextElement();
                String value = props.getProperty(key);
                map.put(key, value);
            }
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } finally{
            if(input!=null){
                try {
                    input.close();
                } catch (IOException e2) {
                    e2.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Bean(name="dataSource", destroyMethod = "close")
    public DataSource getDataSource(){  
        ComboPooledDataSource dataSource = new ComboPooledDataSource();
        try {
            dataSource.setDriverClass(map.get("db.driverClass"));
            dataSource.setJdbcUrl(map.get("db.jdbcUrl"));
            dataSource.setUser(map.get("db.user"));
            dataSource.setPassword(map.get("db.password"));
            dataSource.setMaxPoolSize(50);
            dataSource.setMinPoolSize(5);
            dataSource.setMaxConnectionAge(1800);
            dataSource.setMaxIdleTime(1800);
            dataSource.setAutoCommitOnClose(false);
            dataSource.setInitialPoolSize(5);
        } catch (PropertyVetoException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean(name="sessionFactory")
    @Scope("singleton")
    public  FactoryBean<SessionFactory> getSessionFactory(@Qualifier("dataSource") javax.sql.DataSource dataSource){
        LocalSessionFactoryBean localSessionFactoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", map.get("db.dialect"));
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.jdbc.batch_size", "0");
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("c3p0.acquire_increment", "1");
        localSessionFactoryBean.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties);
        try {
            localSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return localSessionFactoryBean;
    }

    @Bean(name="transactionManager")
    public HibernateTransactionManager getTransactionManager(@Qualifier("sessionFactory") SessionFactory sessionFactory){
        HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        return transactionManager;
    }

    public Map<String, String> getMap() {
        return map;
    }

    public void setMap(Map<String, String> map) {
        this.map = map;
    }
}
```

The output of the stackrace gives me the following exception :

```
ERROR ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com..web.config.HibernateConfig#0' defined in class path resource [META-INF/spring/daoContext.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com..web.config.HibernateConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$49b2842b]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1105)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1050)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:446)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:328)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4939)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com..web.config.HibernateConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$49b2842b]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:163)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:89)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1098)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.Properties$LineReader.readLine(Properties.java:434)
    at java.util.Properties.load0(Properties.java:353)
    at java.util.Properties.load(Properties.java:341)
    at com..web.config.HibernateConfig.init(HibernateConfig.java:35)
    at com..web.config.HibernateConfig.<init>(HibernateConfig.java:26)
    at com..web.config.HibernateConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$49b2842b.<init>(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:147)
    ... 24 more
Jun 16, 2017 2:55:14 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SCHWERWIEGEND: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com..web.config.HibernateConfig#0' defined in class path resource [META-INF/spring/daoContext.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com..web.config.HibernateConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$49b2842b]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1105)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1050)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:446)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:328)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4939)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com..web.config.HibernateConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$49b2842b]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:163)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:89)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1098)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.Properties$LineReader.readLine(Properties.java:434)
    at java.util.Properties.load0(Properties.java:353)
    at java.util.Properties.load(Properties.java:341)
    at com..web.config.HibernateConfig.init(HibernateConfig.java:35)
    at com..web.config.HibernateConfig.<init>(HibernateConfig.java:26)
    at com..web.config.HibernateConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$49b2842b.<init>(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:147)
    ... 24 more

INFO  SessionListener - # flyway migration...
Jun 16, 2017 2:55:14 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SCHWERWIEGEND: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class com..web.listener.FlywayListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com..web.config.HibernateConfig#0' defined in class path resource [META-INF/spring/daoContext.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com..web.config.HibernateConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$49b2842b]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1105)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1050)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:446)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:328)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4939)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com..web.config.HibernateConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$49b2842b]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:163)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:89)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1098)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.Properties$LineReader.readLine(Properties.java:434)
    at java.util.Properties.load0(Properties.java:353)
    at java.util.Properties.load(Properties.java:341)
    at com..web.config.HibernateConfig.init(HibernateConfig.java:35)
    at com..web.config.HibernateConfig.<init>(HibernateConfig.java:26)
    at com..web.config.HibernateConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$49b2842b.<init>(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:147)
    ... 24 more
```

I have been looking for a thread talking about the same issue I could not find any so far. Any one has an idea please?

**UPDATE** : Stacktrace added

Comment: Add the full stacktrace as well

Comment: Your are using Spring, then use Spring. Don't load your own properties, use a `@PropertySource` for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are using Spring, then use Spring. Don't load your own properties, use a `@PropertySource` for that.

Remove your `init` method and replace that with an `@PropertySource`, then inject the `Environment` into your configuration and use that to retrieve properties.

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:jdbc.properties")
public class HibernateConfig {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource(){  
        ComboPooledDataSource dataSource = new ComboPooledDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClass(env.getProperty("db.driverClass"));
        dataSource.setJdbcUrl(env.getProperty("db.jdbcUrl"));
        dataSource.setUser(env.getProperty("db.user"));
        dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("db.password"));
        dataSource.setMaxPoolSize(50);
        dataSource.setMinPoolSize(5);
        dataSource.setMaxConnectionAge(1800);
        dataSource.setMaxIdleTime(1800);
        dataSource.setAutoCommitOnClose(false);
        dataSource.setInitialPoolSize(5);
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory(DataSource dataSource){
        LocalSessionFactoryBean localSessionFactoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", map.get("db.dialect"));
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.jdbc.batch_size", "0");
        localSessionFactoryBean.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties);
        localSessionFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
        return localSessionFactoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory sessionFactory){
        return new HibernateTransactionManager(sessionFactory);
    }
}
```

Some other related things

1. Don't catch `Exception`s during bean setup, let the configuration blow up else your application is in some weird state.
2. You are injecting a `DataSource` into the `LocalSessionFactoryBean` which makes explicit property settings useless.
3. The `close` method of a `DataSource` is automatically detected.
4. You don't need all those `@Qualifier` annotations
5. Try to be as specific as possible in your return types on `@Bean` methods, this is needed to have proper callbacks applied.
6. Don't call `afterPropertiesSet` yourself Spring will do that for you.

Comment: Thank you for your reply